Unable to connect to RabbitMQ within Docker containers
I'm trying to set up a RabbitMQ instance using Docker, but I'm having trouble connecting to it from another service within the same Docker Compose network. Here's what I have so far:
Docker Compose File:
version: '3.8'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - my-network

  server:
    build:
      context: ./Server
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - my-network
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq

  worker:
    build:
      context: ./workers
    container_name: python_worker
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_URL: amqp://localhost:5672
    networks:
      - my-network
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge

I can access the RabbitMQ management interface at http://localhost:15672, but my my-service application can't connect to RabbitMQ using the RABBITMQ_URL: amqp://rabbitmq:5672.
The error message I receive is: Error: Unable to connect to RabbitMQ server.
What I've Tried:
Verified that both services are on the same Docker network (my-network).
Ensured that the RABBITMQ_URL in my-service is set to amqp://rabbitmq:5672, which should be the correct internal URL.
Checked the RabbitMQ logs, but didn't find anything helpful.
Questions:
What might be causing the connection issue between my service and RabbitMQ within Docker?
Are there any additional steps I should take to debug or configure the network settings?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

(It shouldn't make any difference, but you should be able to delete all of the networks: and container_name: blocks in the file.  The RabbitMQ container might need volumes: for persistence, and as a special case for that specific image it might need an explicit hostname:.)

You quite clearly have RABBITMQ_URL: amqp://localhost:5672 in your worker environment config. I also cannot see any my-service service
